# Inconsistent createFromFormat return (PHP)

Tags: php

This works (note the single digit ".3")

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("*-*-*.*.*-Y-m-d-H?i.*", "backup-bla-3.3.3-2019-08-23-21h16.7z");
```

This fails (note the double digit ".33" :

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("*-*-*.*.*-Y-m-d-H?i.*", "backup-bla-3.3.33-2019-08-23-21h16.7z");
```

This makes no sense to me. Why doesn't the `*` succeed in this case ?

The following also works on this specific example but I cannot make use of it as the version numbers may have double digits.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("*-*-*.*.??-Y-m-d-H?i.*", "backup-bla-3.3.33-2019-08-23-21h16.7z");
```

Comment: This is clearly the defined behaviour according to [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). "Random bytes until the next separator or digit." You'll have to use a regular expression or something similar before createFromFormat. Something like `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d-H?i", preg_replace("[^([^-]+-){3}([^.]+).*$]", "$2", "backup-bla-3.3.33-2019-08-23-21h16.7z"));`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why it fails when using `*` is clear from [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

> Random bytes until the next separator or digit

You have two digits in a row `3` and `3` so when it reaches the second `3` your provided format is incorrect and causes an error.

The inverse is true with `**` and `??` because when you have a single digit number there is no second character for the second `*` and `?` to match.

I don't see any way around this using the available format characters. Your solution seems to be modifying that value to remove anything before the year and then using `Datetime:createFromFormat()`.

```
$parts = preg_split('/(?=\d{4})/', 'backup-bla-3.3.3-2019-08-23-21h16.7z', -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d-H?i.*", $parts[1]);
echo $date->format('c');
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/N50Op)

Comment: And if the string is "backup-bla-3.3.3333-2019-08-23-21h16.7z"? ;)

Comment: @MattRaines That regex can certainly be improved. I went more for concept then final code. When I get a chance I'll fix that.